# Maximum execution time exceeded when adding or updating plugins from the Control Panel

Tags: error-message

When I try to install or update a plugin from the Control Panel, I see a message "***Updating Composer Dependencies***" and then the following error occurs. I'm running Craft on a local environment. Installing and updating from the command line works fine.

```
Status: Internal Server Error

Response:
PHP Fatal Error &#039;yii\base\ErrorException&#039; with message &#039;Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded&#039;
in ...\vendor\composer\composer\src\Composer\Util\RemoteFilesystem.php:555

Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: yii\base\ErrorHandler-&gt;handleFatalError()
#1 {main}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to figure out where your PHP config file is located (`php.ini`) and increase the value for the [`max_execution_time` setting](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time).

---

The best way to locate your `php.ini`:

- If you can run `php` from the command line, run `php --ini`. Alternatively you could use `php -i | grep 'Configuration File'` to search the full `phpinfo()`. [More info...](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2750580/4914302)
- If `php` isn't accessible via the CLI, you can also create a simple php file that contains the following snippet. Load it up in your browser and search the page for "Configuration File". This will give you the location of your `php.ini`.

```
<?php

phpinfo();
```

Other options:

- If you're using a Laravel Valet / Homebrew setup, the `php.ini` file is located at `/usr/local/etc/php/X.X/php.ini` where `X.X` is your PHP version number.
- If you're running MAMP Pro, I believe they provide a built in editor to customize this - see [*How do you change php.ini values in MAMP Pro?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37824946/4914302)

Comment: I updated the timeout and ran the updater for Craft CMS and now the previous installation seems to be blown out. Warning: require(vendor/craftcms/cms/bootstrap/web.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Users\rickn\Documents\Craft\Projects\Untye\web\index.php on line 20

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'vendor/craftcms/cms/bootstrap/web.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in

Comment: try removing your `vendor` folder entirely and run `composer install` from the command line...

Comment: Thanks. Then I get - The requested package craftcms/cms (locked at 3.0.34, required as 3.0.35) is satisfiable by craftcms/cms[3.0.34] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.